# Getting error in source tree when trying to pull--> In source tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/project': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because [GitHub has deprecated TLS v1](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/) since February 22nd.

See of your Git is part of the [Known incompatible clients](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/#known-incompatible-clients).
At the very least, upgrade Git or any other component making Git operations (JGit, EGit, ...)

In your case, install the latest Git, and make sure

- SourceTree is up-to-date
- SourceTree is using the System Git, not the embedded one.
  Or at least, as the OP comments, update the embedded one.

As a workaround, pending updates, you can still switch to an SSH URL if your remote server allows it.

Comment: See also https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-do-I-setup-Sourcetree-to-access-Github-now-that-they/qaq-p/735377. I prefer installing my own Git rather than relying on the embedded one in SourceTree.

Comment: it worked vice-versa for me....

 update git version 1.9.5 to 2.15.1 using steps: In sourceTree go to Tools>options>GIT>Use Embedded GIT

Comment: @DeadEnd 2.15.1 is good enough then. I have updated the answer accordingly.